# How to get (partial) variables from a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, path

I don't know regular expressions so well, I have a doubt regarding the possibility to get partials variables from a regex check. I try to explain what I am looking for...

I have those kind of paths:

```
example.com/dir1/
example.com/dir1/val1
example.com/dir1/val1-val2
```

I would like to create an expression that extracts **dir1 val1** and **val2**.

My questions is:

Can I extract only the variables that exists or do I have to write 3 expressions? I mean...

If I put a rule to use: `example.com/dir1/val1-val2`

Can I only get dir1 if I pass url like: `www.example.com/category` (dir1 = category) ?

then If the url was: `www.example.com/category/car`

get `dir1 = category` and `val1 = car`

Comment: @stivlo, how can I use explode? the urls could be subdivided by many characters, like: example.com/val1-val2/dir1 or example.com/dir1/dir2/val1_val2 etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode("/", $url)` is easiest if possible. If the structure is more complex than that allows for, you could use preg_split() instead and list all the possible characters that can be used as subdividers.

```
$urlParts = preg_split('/[_\/-]/', $url);
```

Comment: I think i have to trim for those characters before otherwise the first element f the array would be empty.

Comment: $urlParts = preg_split('/[_\/-]/', $v, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); does the job perfectly!!! thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode('/', $url); to get an array with all your values, regular expressions shouldn't be used to solve problems like this